# Is there any other ways than listing?

Tags: probability

> So there was this question, confusing for me and I know it would help me in the future tests in the subject If I managed to know how it works. So thanks in advance for the help.

Consider the Code 39 consisting of narrow and wide bars (black) separated by either wide or narrow spaces (white). Each character contains nine elements (five bars and four spaces). The code for a character starts and ends with a bar (either narrow or wide) and a (white) space appears between each bar. The original specification (since revised) used exactly two wide bars and one wide space in each character. For example, if *b* and *B* denote narrow and wide (black) bars, respectively, and *w* and *W* denote narrow
and wide (white) spaces, a valid character is *bwBwBW bwb* (the number 6).

So the number of other characters that can be coded for the system is 40.

Since, the number of permutations of five black bars when two are *B* and three are *b* is 5!/ 2! 3! = 10

And with three narrow spaces *w* and one wide space *W*, there are 4!/3!1! = 4

Thus, 10×4 = 40

But if asked, what is the probability a) that the first bar is wide or the second bar is wide? b) that the first space is wide or the second space is wide?

> If it's asking for the bars, should I only use the 10 or the whole set of possible codes (40) ? Also, how could I find out about the second bar and space?

> I tried computing and I always end up with answer more than 40, which is so wrong and proves that I'm really lost.

EDIT: I tried to manually list all the codes that satisfies the condition and from that I've got the correct answer ( in the comments) but is there any other ways to compute other than listing?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question about the bars, you can just focus on the 10 permutations of the bars. Count how many satisfy "the first bar is wide or the second bar is wide", and divide by 10.

Similarly for the spaces, focus on the 4 permutations of spaces; count how many satisfy the condition, and divide by 4.

Comment: Nice, but I don't think I should divide it by 10 since it's asking about the probability among the set of all possible codes. BTW, did you mean I should count manually as in listing or is there other ways to count( like some formula of permutations/ combinations or something that uses counting techniques? ahm, I tried to manually list  and count and finally got 7, times 4 ( the number of permutations of spaces) which is 28/40, ending up with a probability of 0.7. but then, thanks for the tip about focusing on the bars and spaces.

Comment: @keplerxx Your approach (counting all possible codes) yields $\frac{7 \cdot 4}{10 \cdot 4}$. My approach (focusing only on bars) yields $\frac{7}{10}$. Do you see why it is ok to just focus on the bars even when they ask about the probability over all possible codes?